# Implementing an in-app purchase auto renewing subscription on an Apple Watch app?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, apple-watch, subscription, auto-renewing

My watch app will put a portion of its features behind a subscription paywall, I'm following a few tutorials I found re: implementing an auto-renewing subscription: [savvyapps](https://savvyapps.com/blog/how-setup-test-auto-renewable-subscription-ios-app) and [RW](https://www.raywenderlich.com/154737/app-purchases-auto-renewable-subscriptions-tutorial)

Is there any reason I cannot/should not build this code on watch and have the user make the purchase there?  Or should I write the IAP code on the iPhone app and pass a subscribed `Bool` message to the watch upon load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StoreKit is not available in WatchOS.  The user has to make the purchase on the iPhone, then use `WCSession` to pass a message to the watch to keep whether the user's subscription is current in sync.